# Rails, how to change automatic generated link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, auto-generate

I have a RoR app. And in app users can create posts. I've connected Posts table in my `routes.rb` via `resources :posts`. And right now - link to created post look like: `http://mysitename.com/posts/1` (where 1 is post number).

What i want to do, is to make rails  generate link to post. So users didn't see how much posts I have in my DB. And as result it must look like `http://mysitename.com/post/generatedlink`. It must generate, for example post theme.

For start, we must create `link` column in Posts table. And make it to generate something like that:

```
@post.link = @post.theme.parameterize.underscore
```

But I don't understand, where to put this code.

And the next problem is: "How to replace `post/1` for `@post.link`?"

Hope, I make my self clear. If you'll say I can provide information, what is needed to resolve my question.

*UPDATE*

What I did after @SteveTurczyn advise.

I've created new column, called `random_link` as a `string`.

I didn't touch my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
```

My `post.rb` (post model) look like this:

```
after_validation  :add_link 

def add_link
  self.random_link = self.theme.to_slug_param 
  # to_slug_param it's a gem for translating from other language into english
end

def to_param
  random_link
end
```

I don't have find method. My `posts_controller.rb` look like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_random_link(params[:id])
  right_menu_posts
  random_link_to_other_post(@post)
end

  private 

  def random_link_to_other_post(post)
    random_post = Post.where.not(id: post.id)
    @random_post = random_post.sort_by {rand}.first
  end

  def right_menu_posts
    @posts_for_video_in_right_menu = Post.where(video: true)
  end
```

And html.erb:

```
<%= @post.theme %>
<%= @post.content %>

<% for post in @random_post %>
  <%= link_to post %>
<% end %>
<% for post in @posts_for_video_in_right_menu %>
  <%= link_to post %>
<% end %>
```

And on a main page (where i have a list of posts) a keep getting an error: `NoMethodError in Home#index private method 'to_param' called for #<Post:0x007fae3096bf78>`.

Comment: perhaps look at this gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id However it's worth understanding how to do this without a gem, for learning purposes, since it's not that difficult to implement.

Comment: You shouldn't have `to_param` in the private part of your model definition. I've modified my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique is referred to as `slugifying` and you need to do three things...

(1) create a new field called `slug` in your `posts` table.

(2) add this code to your `Post` model...

```
after_validation :generate_slug

private

def generate_slug
  self.slug = theme.parameterize.underscore
end

public

def to_param
  slug
end
```

(3) finally, in your controllers where you have `find_post` methods, rewrite it to be...

```
def find_post
  Post.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

The `to_param` method in the model is how things like `post_path(@post)` build the url... the `to_param` if not replaced substituted the `id` field but by writing your own `to_param` method you can ensure that the `slug` field is substituted instead.

Ensure that 'to_param' is a public method!  Don't put it in the private part of your model.  You can do that by putting `public` immediately before the `to_param` method.  You should then put `private` after the method definition if subsequent methods are to be private.

Comment: I get it. Nice way. But as the result link_to tag work different now. For example: it was `<%= link_to @post %>`, but now it works like this: `<%= link_to @post.slug %>` (in my app it `@post.random_link`). May be you could help me how to fix it?

Comment: No you can still do `link_to @post` because of the to_param change

Comment: Add to question post what problem is appears

Comment: I've modified my answer to clarify, but basically you made `to_param` a private method, not a public method.